# pineapple open face chinese shooting the moon

Tags: open-face-chinese, pineapple, shoot-the-moon

When you shoot the moon in pineapple OFC, do you get 20 points, but the other player always scoops you? or does your hand not get scooped because it shot the moon?

Comment: I closed your question because Open Face Chinese poker is waaay too different and disconnected from what we consider to be actual poker. Generally, questions should be about any form of poker from the Hold'em, Stud or Draw families (about 10 games in total if I remember correctly).

Comment: PS: If there will be enough interest, we could modify the rules to accept these more exotic forms of poker.

Comment: So is there no place to post this on stackexchange then?

Comment: The only one I can think of is http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/ , but I'm not 100 % sure it's ontopic there. It may be, try asking on their Meta site about it ;) .

Comment: @RaduMurzea OFC is becoming more and more popular, and I think this question should be allowed here. The help centre just says "Poker Stack Exchange is for serious players and enthusiasts of poker." I think any variant of poker which uses the standard five card poker hands (flush, full house, two pair, etc) should be on topic. Similar to how on StackOverflow there are some languages that are not as popular, but are still on topic. Tags help people find questions that are relevant to them.

Comment: OFC is a very popular variant of poker. I don't see why it wouldn't be allowed.

Comment: http://meta.poker.stackexchange.com/questions/187/add-open-face-chinese discussion here

Comment: @Paulpro I was basing my decision mostly on what was discussed here: http://meta.poker.stackexchange.com/q/179/309 . Since both games are kind of "exotic", I considered that it would be best to apply the same treatment to them. Though there is a 50/50 chance that I'm wrong, I want more opinions, especially from the other moderators. Also, no matter what we decide, we should make the help page more specific on what is allowed and what is not.

Comment: I've added an answer to the meta question. I think OFC is on-topic. @RaduMurzea makes a good point about the specifics of what "poker" is and is not. I've tried to address a couple of those points in the meta answer.

Comment: Per the discussions here and on Meta, I have decided to reopen your question, it's ontopic :) .

Answer (score 1):

Since it is **very** hard to shoot the moon in POFC, other players do not scoop you if you get there. So you gain 20 points from each player.

Otherwise the risk you take would (by far) not be worth the outcome. (Imo, I think that 20 points from each player is still not enough to make this play profitable.)